# Excel: How to replace missing values with numbers from a series?

Tags: excel, replace

I made a formula that checks column A and returns the position in column B in which the value from the former matches; unless a value from column A is not found in column B or the same value is duplicated in column A, in which case it returns "NA". Here's an example of what I mean.

```
    A   B   Output
1   ABB AAB 2
2   AAB ABB 1
3   BCA BCA 3
4   BDA BDA 4
5   AFA BEA 7
6   BDA AGB NA
7   BEA AFA 5
8   BFB BHA NA
9   BHA CEB 8
10  BEC DEB NA
11  BED BED 11
12  DEB     10
13  DID     NA
```

Now I would like to replace the NAs with the numbers from the rows that are missing in the output (in this case: 6, 9, 12, and 13), in order. The result would be something like this.

```
    A   B   Output
1   ABB AAB 2
2   AAB ABB 1
3   BCA BCA 3
4   BDA BDA 4
5   AFA BEA 7
6   BDA AGB 6
7   BEA AFA 5
8   BFB BHA 9
9   BHA CEB 8
10  BEC DEB 12
11  BED BED 11
12  DEB     10
13  DID     13
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: I think this can only be done with a helper column with the formula `=IFNA(C2,C1+1)`. This will work if your output column is sorted from lowest to highest and there are no gaps bigger than one.

Answer (score 0):

Without using VBA, it would be near impossible to create an array of missing numbers and assign it to the `#N/A` gaps.

However if you sort your dataset from low to high in the output column, you'll get a clear counter with gaps. Then you can write the following formula to fill the gaps: (where C is your output column and D is where the formula goes)

`=IFNA(C2,IF(ISBLANK(D1),IFNA(C2,C1+1),D1+1))`

This will take the number of the previous hit in column C and add 1 to it. Unless the previous hit was empty, in that case it will add 1 to the last hit of this formula instead (this accounts for gaps bigger than 1).

After this you can paste by value and merge the columns.